# facebook c# sdk - list group members and feed

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-group

Trying to list the membership of a group I own, as well as view the posts of this group.

I have tried

```
fbclient.get("/groups/mygroupname/members");
```

returns an error:

```
(OAuthException - #2500) Unknown path components: /members
```

I am using an user token from one of my applications.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send request `{your group id}/members`.
To find out `group id`, just send me/groups and find according `group id` by `name`